# Create ingress deployment with Minikube

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, minikube, nginx-ingress, kustomize

I'm going through [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/ingress-minikube/) tutorial to create a deployment and an ingress controller on Minikube. When I run, as instructed in the tutorial, `curl --resolve "hello-world.info:80:$( minikube ip )" -i http://hello-world.info` I simply get `HTTP/1.1 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable`.

Here are my deployment, service, ingress and kustomization files:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: example-deployment
  labels:
    app: example
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: example
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: example
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: localhost:5000/example-app:latest
        ports:
        - name: web
          containerPort: 80

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: example
spec:
  ports:
    - name: web
      port: 80
      targetPort: web
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: example

---

apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: example-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
  rules:
  - host: hello-world.info
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: example
            port:
              number: 80

---

apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization
metadata:
  name: arbitrary

# Example configuration for the webserver
# at https://github.com/monopole/hello
commonLabels:
  app: example

resources:
- deployment.yaml
- service.yaml
- ingress.yaml
```

Here is the output from `kubectl get ingress`:

```
NAME              CLASS   HOSTS              ADDRESS        PORTS   AGE
example-ingress   nginx   hello-world.info   192.168.49.2   80      3m29s
```

Here is the output from `kubectl get services`:

```
kubectl get services
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
example      ClusterIP   10.109.63.32   <none>        80/TCP    10m
```

So as you can see everything is up and running. Here is my nginx:

```
[jenia@archlinux ibn-battuta]$ kubectl get pods -n ingress-nginx
NAME                                        READY   STATUS      RESTARTS   AGE
ingress-nginx-admission-create-fvj4v        0/1     Completed   0          3h37m
ingress-nginx-admission-patch-d4xfn         0/1     Completed   1          3h37m
ingress-nginx-controller-7799c6795f-7qgsr   1/1     Running     0          3h37m
```

Here are the logs of nginx 503:

```
192.168.49.1 - - [29/Aug/2023:01:11:43 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 503 190 "-" "curl/8.2.1" 79 0.000 [default-example-80] [] - - - - e03c2a5e71db02f27f1afca0905c6c36
```

If anyone can help me, it'll be greatly appreciated.

Comment: your deployment pod running ? 503 mean service unavailable check the status if it's running or crashing and try port-forward from svc once and debug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Jenia Ivanov

`targetPort` is incorrect in your `example` service

`selector` in `example` service doesnot match the `label` of your `pod` in your `deployment yaml`

Could you update  `targetPort` and `selector` in your service  as shown below and verify?

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: example
spec:
  ports:
    - name: web
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
  selector:
    app: example
```

Comment: Thanks!! I changed `app.kubernetes.io/name` to `app` and it worked. I do not understand why as in the [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) they use `app.kubernetes.io/name` and not `name`.

Comment: Also when I tried to deploy this service to EKS (without kustomize) I had `app.kubernetes.io/name` and not `app` and it was working. Is this difference specific to minikube?

Comment: the [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) and [this doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/ingress-minikube/) are 2 different documentation describing different usecases. you have to follow [this doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/ingress-minikube/) for minikube setup

Comment: @JeniaIvanov i have to look into the scripts that were used to deploy in EKS to answer your question

Comment: The service script I used in eks is exactly like [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#defining-a-service). It does not work with minikube however and to make it work I had to change `app.kubernetes.io/name` to `app`. That's what made it work. However in [the minikube doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/ingress-minikube/) it does not say to use `app` instead of `app.kubernetes.io/name`. I'd like to eventually understand why the difference and how does one find out to use `app` with minikube. Thank you kindly for your help so far!!